Как поместить фон шапки на передний план?
Есть две секции, header и welcome. Для них нужно сделать общий фон, как на картинке Я написала вот так:
    .welcome {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     min-height: 100vh;

     margin-top: -140px;
     padding: 240px 0;

     background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
     background-color: #252525;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;

Но теперь не отображается бэкграунд у хедера

Можно ли как-то вынести его на передний план? Или может как-то по-другому сделать фон на две секции

Дать header белый background-color пытались? Для полноценного совета недостаточно увидеть картинки, нужен модельный код, чтобы мы увидели проблему именно в коде и смогли предложить корректировки.

Да, цвет задавать пыталась и через z-index, тоже не получилось
.header {
margin-top: 40px;
font-weight: 600;
background-color: #fff;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 80px;
}

Приведенные вами части кода не демонстрируют проблему. Исправьте вопрос, добавьте код, в котором ваша проблема воспроизводится.

В общем я знаю, что не так у вас, у вас проблема вложенности, вы не правильно z-index задаёте. z-index работает между элементами, которые находятся на одном уровне друг с другом, поэтому вы должны найти начальную точку кода, в которой находится меню и на том же уровне элемент в котором находится всё остальное и задавать этим уже элементам z-index. Было дело сам парился с таким, когда приходилось чужой замудрёный код дорабатывать, а вёрстку при этом нельзя было трогать, так как сайт был в продкшене
